# Projection of a point onto a sphere proof verification?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

I wanted to work out how to project plane curves onto a sphere, and I started with projecting a single arbitrary point uniquely onto a sphere, and I arrived at the following conclusions. Can someone check my work?

Suppose there exists a point in the plane, $(x_0, y_0, 0)$ (such that this point does not lie on or within the unit circle in the plane centered at the origin), and a unit sphere that is tangent to the plane at the origin. Then $(x_0, y_0, 0)$ can be uniquely projected onto the sphere by drawing a line in the space that
1) intersects the point $(x_0, y_0, 0)$
2) intersects the $z$-axis at the point $(0. 0, z_0)$ 
3) does not lie in the plane, and
4) is tangent to the sphere at the point $(x_t, y_t, z_t)$
Then the point $(x_t, y_t, z_t)$ is the unique projection of $(x_0, y_0, 0)$ onto the sphere, and its coordinates can be calculated by the following system of equations:
1)$$\alpha = \sqrt{ \frac{ (x_t - x_0)^2 + (y_t - y_0)^2 + z_t^2 }{ x_t^2 + y_t^2 + (z_0 - z_t)^2 } }$$
2)$$x_0 + (x_t - x_0)(1 + \alpha) = 0$$
3)$$y_0 + (y_t - y_0)(1 + \alpha) = 0$$
4)$$z_t (1+\alpha) = z_0$$
5)$$z_0 = \frac{ -(x_t x_0 + y_t y_0) }{ \sqrt{ 1 -x_t^2 -y_t^2 } }$$